# The repository does not have Release file

Tags: linux, debian

Got error while run following command.

```bash
sudo lb build
```

Following is the error.

```
P: Configuring file /etc/apt/sources.list
Hit:1 http://ftp.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org bookworm/updates InRelease
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org bookworm/updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:24::644 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org bookworm/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
P: Begin unmounting filesystems...
P: Saving caches...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
```

Context: Currently reading the Debian Live Manual and running the commands from [4. The Basics](https://live-team.pages.debian.net/live-manual/html/live-manual/the-basics.en.html#178) chapter.

```bash
lb -v
3.0~a57-1
```

The system I'm currently using is Linux Mint 21.1

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.